# Change Hash Function in CakePHP 2.2.1

Tags: cakephp, hash

Can someone explain to me how to change the Hash Function in CakePHP 2.2.1 ?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `Security::setHash()` to set the default or you can use the second argument to `Security::hash()` for the hash type.

[API for setHash](http://api.cakephp.org/class/security#method-SecuritysetHash)

[API for hash](http://api.cakephp.org/class/security#method-Securityhash)